# Phonegap SQLite performance speed load

Tags: jquery, html, css, sqlite, cordova

I'am a newbie in Android programming, I want to ask how to speed up my phonegap sqlite application. in there have 150 words, but when i push refresh button, it's need 30 sec to load. Can anyone help me to improve that?

I want to fill the database up to 500 words and can I show the words without pressing the refresh button?

```
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    }  
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Database Sqlite", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

 $(document).ready(function(){

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "KamusDB", 200000);

            function onDeviceReady(){
                //Populate the database
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
                //Override the back button functionality
                document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBack, false);
            }

            function onBack(){
                //If the current page is index page then exit other wise navigate to index page
                if($.mobile.activePage.is('#index')){
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else{
                    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
                }
            }              

            function populateDB(tx){
                //Create the table
                //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyContacts');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyContacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, jerman TEXT, indonesia TEXT)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (1, "Aber", "Tapi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (2, "Abfall", "Sampah")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (3, "Abkommen", "Persetujuan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (4, "Abreise", "Keberangkatan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (5, "Abschied", "Perpisahan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (6, "Abendessen", "Makan Malam")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (7, "Alter", "Umur")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (9, "Absicht", "Niat")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (10, "Abstand", "Jarak")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (11, "Abstimmung", "Suara dalam pemilihan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (12, "Abtreibung", "Aborsi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (13, "Affe", "Monyet")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (14, "Adresse", "Alamat")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (15, "Ahnung", "Ide")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (16, "Adler", "Elang")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (17, "Apfelsine", "Orange")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (18, "Baum", "Pohon")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (19, "Bart", "Jenggot")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (20, "Beamte", "Pegawai Negeri Sipil")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (21, "Banane", "Pisang")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (22, "Baumwolle", "Kapas")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (23, "Bedeutung", "Penting")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (24, "Bedeckt", "Mendung")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (25, "Befugnis", "Kewenangan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (26, "Brot", "Roti")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (27, "Chef", "Bos")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (28, "Chirurgin", "Operasi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (29, "Creme", "Krim")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (30, "Clown", "Badut")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (31, "Circa", "Kira kira")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (32, "Chemie", "Kimia")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (33, "Champignon", "Jamur")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (34, "Charakteristisch", "Karakterisitik")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (35, "Chinesich", "Cina")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (36, "Computer", "Komputer")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (37, "Dach", "Atap")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (38, "Darlehen", "Pinjaman")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (39, "Darstellerin", "Aktris")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (40, "Darsteller", "Aktor")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (41, "Degen", "Pedang")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (42, "Dehnbar", "Elastis")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (43, "Dreckig", "Kotor")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (44, "Drachen", "Layangan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (45, "Diebstahl", "Pencuri")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (46, "Disziplin", "Disiplin")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (47, "Eckig", "Kotak")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (48, "Egoistisch", "Egois")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (49, "Ehre", "Kehormatan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (50, "Ehrgeiz", "Ambisi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (51, "Eigentum", "Properti")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (52, "Eimer", "Ember")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (53, "Einfall", "Ide")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (54, "Einfluss", "Influenza")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (55, "Einheitlich", "Seragam")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (56, "Erlebnis", "Pengalaman")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (57, "Fenster", "Jendela")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (58, "Ferien", "Liburan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (59, "Feuerwerk", "Kembang Api")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (60, "Fluch", "Kutukan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (61, "Finderlohn", "Penghargaan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (62, "Fleisch", "Daging")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (63, "Fuhrer", "Pemimpin")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (64, "Galgen", "Tiang gantungan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (65, "Gans", "Angsa")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (66, "Ganztagz", "Sepanjang hari")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (67, "Garten", "Kebun")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (68, "Gasthof", "Penginapan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (69, "Gebet", "Doa")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (70, "Geburtsdatum", "Tanggal lahir")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (71, "Gebiss", "Gigi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (72, "Gedicht", "Puisi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (73, "Gefangene", "Tahanan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (74, "Gutschein", "Kupon")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (75, "Handel", "Pertukaran")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (76, "Hass", "Kebencian")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (77, "Hengst", "Kuda jantan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (78, "Herlich", "Menakjubkan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (79, "Industrie", "Industri")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (80, "Ingwer", "Jahe")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (81, "Insel", "Pulau")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (82, "Irrtum", "Kesalahan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (83, "Jahreszeit", "Musim")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (84, "Jagd", "Berburu")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (85, "Jawohl", "Ya")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (86, "Jura", "Hukum")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (87, "Jedoch", "Bagaimanapun")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (88, "Kalt", "Dingin")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (89, "Kamm", "Sisir")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (90, "Kein", "No")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (91, "Katze", "Kucing")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (92, "Kleingeld", "Ganti")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (93, "Lachs", "Salmon")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (94, "Muster", "Model")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (95, "Mowe", "Burung Camar")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (96, "Mude", "Lelah")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (97, "Merkmal", "Fitur")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (98, "Neld", "Cemburu")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (99, "Nachbarin", "Tetangga")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (100, "Nass", "Basah")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (101, "Nutzen", "Keuntungan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (102, "Nochmals", "Lagi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (103, "Neun", "Sembilan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (104, "Pflege", "Peduli")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (105, "Pinsel", "Sikat")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (106, "Plakat", "Poster")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (107, "Polizei", "Polisi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (108, "Preis", "Harga")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (109, "Promille", "Kadar Alkohol")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (110, "Pult", "Meja")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (111, "Quelle", "Sumber")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (112, "Qualitat", "Kualitas")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (113, "Quittung", "Resep")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (114, "Razzia", "Serangan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (115, "Rechnen", "Aritmatika")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (116, "Rauch", "Merokok")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (117, "Rassistich", "Rasis")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (118, "Ritter", "Kesatria")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (119, "Rot", "Merah")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (120, "Schelm", "Bajingan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (121, "Schauspielerin", "Aktor")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (122, "Schande", "Malu")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (123, "Sekunde", "Detik")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (124, "Smoking", "Jas makan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (125, "Stein", "Batu")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (126, "Treibstoff", "Bensin")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (127, "Treffen", "Rapat")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (128, "Tat", "Aksi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (129, "Teigh", "Adonan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (130, "Tier", "Hewan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (131, "Uberschwemmung", "Banjir")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (132, "Uberfall", "Serangan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (133, "Unkraut", "Ganja")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (134, "Unfug", "Tidak masuk akal")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (135, "Unterlagen", "Dokumen")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (136, "Vater", "Ayah")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (137, "Verhandlung", "Mendengar")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (138, "Verrat", "Pengkhianat")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (139, "Vogel", "Burung")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (140, "Verwaltung", "Administrasi")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (141, "Wahr", "Betul")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (142, "Weil", "Karena")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (143, "Wecker", "Jam Alarm")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (144, "Wurst", "Sosis")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (145, "X-mal", "Sekian kali")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (146, "X-beliebig", "Apa saja")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (147, "Yoga", "Yoga")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (148, "Yacht", "Kapal pesiar")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (149, "Zug", "Kereta")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (150, "Zeiger", "Tangan")');



                tx.executeSql('SELECT id, jerman, indonesia FROM MyContacts ORDER BY jerman', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
            }

            function successCB(){
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            }

            function queryDB(tx){
                tx.executeSql('SELECT id, jerman, indonesia FROM MyContacts ORDER BY jerman', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
            }

            function querySuccess(tx, results){
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
                var len = results.rows.length;
                $("#userList").html('');
                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var row= results.rows.item(i);
                    var htmlData = '<li id="'+row["id"]+'"><a href="#"><h2>'+row["jerman"]+'</h2><p class="ui-li-aside">'+row["indonesia"]+'</p></a></li>';
                    $("#userList").append(htmlData).listview('refresh');
                }
                $.mobile.changePage($("#index"), { transition : "slide"});
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            }

            function errorCB(err){

            }      


            $(".refresh").bind("click", function (event){
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
            });

            $("#index [data-role='content'] ul").on('tap taphold', 'li', function (event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var liId = this.id;
                if (event.type === 'taphold'){
                    navigator.notification.vibrate(30);
                    var $popup = $('#actionList-popup');
                    $("#actionList").html('');
                    $popup.popup();
                    $popup.popup('open');
                    $("#tapHoldCheck").val('true');
                }
                else if (event.type === 'tap'){
                    if ($("#tapHoldCheck").val() == ''){ //If the value of the text box is blank then only tap will work
                        db.transaction(function (tx){
                            tx.executeSql("SELECT jerman, indonesia  FROM MyContacts WHERE id=?;", [liId], function (tx, results){
                                var row = results.rows.item(0);
                                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
                                $.mobile.changePage($("#displayDataPage"), { transition : "slide"});
                                $("#nameHeader").html(row['jerman']);
                                $("#datajerman").html(row['jerman']);
                                $("#dataindonesia").html(row['indonesia']);
                                $('#dataList').listview('refresh');
                                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                            });
                         });
                    }
                }
            });

            //Change the hidden field value when the popup is closed
            $('#actionList-popup').bind({
                popupafterclose: function(event, ui){
                    $("#tapHoldCheck").val('');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

    </head>
```

```
    <!-- Index Page Start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
         <a href="#" class="refresh" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="a" title="Refresh">Refresh</a>
            <h1 class="in">Jerman Dictionary</h1>
             <a href="#right-panel" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-theme="a" title="Menu" >Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="false" data-divider-theme="e" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." id="userList">  </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="actionList-popup" data-overlay-theme="m">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="actionList" style="border: 1px solid blue; width:15em">  </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="tapHoldCheck" value="" />
    </div>
    <!-- Index Page End -->

    <!-- Data Display Page Start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="displayDataPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
            <h1>Penjelasan</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="e" id="dataList">
                <li>Jerman =  <span id="datajerman"></span></li>
                <li>Indonesia =  <span id="dataindonesia"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Data Display Page End -->




     </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few notices:

- You are now making lots of *INSERT*s as separate queries. Instead you could try like this

with multiple INSERTs on same execution:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (1, "Aber", "Tapi");
INSERT INTO MyContacts (id, jerman, indonesia) VALUES (2, "Abfall", "Sampah");');
```

- Your *SELECT* query in the end of `tx.executeSql`s needs to be put into the success callback of the concatenated inserts

like this

```
tx.executeSql('<inserts here>', [], function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT id, jerman, indonesia FROM MyContacts ORDER BY jerman', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
});
```

If those don't help, add *alert* to track when it starts and ends to do the SQL queries to see how much those actually take time.

Comment: i'am sorry, i don't understand in this parts `tx.executeSql('<inserts here>', [], function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT id, jerman, indonesia FROM MyContacts ORDER BY jerman', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
});` , can you explain again,please ?

Comment: @BayuDanangW: I hope you know about the [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) nature of SQL execution. As you run _executeSql_, it isn't immediately done just like when you do AJAX request from your browser, you need to wait for the server to respond. Instead it might take for example few seconds to be done and you need to synchronize your application to wait until it is done. This is done via success [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) that are the third parameter passed for the _executeSql_.